# Struts 2 - Populate s:select from server based on first s:select

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have multiple select boxes on my jsp - when a user selects the first select box I need to query the database through my Action class in order to populate the second select box (and so on).

I'm able to correctly display and select the values for the first select box, but cannot figure out a way to query the db for the second values based on the first. Here is the code that works for the first select. Any suggestions on a good approach to getting the second select populated based on the first would be greatly appreciated.

**JSP**

```xml
<s:form action="fileUploadAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:div>
        <s:select label="Select #1:" list="select1Map"  listKey="key" 
              listValue="value" name="select1" headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="--Select a Value--"/>
    </s:div>
    <s:div>
        <s:select label="Select #2:" list="select2Map" listKey="key" 
              listValue="value" name="select2" headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="--Select an Value--"/>
    </s:div>

</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="fileUpload" class="fileUploadAction" method="display">
    <result name="success">/jsp/dataUpload/fileUpload.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**FileUploadAction.java**

```
public class FileUploadAction extends AbstractAction{
private Map<Object, String> select1Map;
private Map<Object, String> select2Map;

private FileUploadService service = null;

public FileUploadAction(){
    super();
}

public String display(){
    select1Map= service.getDataForDropDown(getUser().getId());
    select2Map = new HashMap<Object,String>();

    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the properties corresponding to the selected values, check if the first is not empty/null, in that case load the second map too:

```
public class FileUploadAction extends AbstractAction{

    @Inject FileUploadService service;

    @Getter         private Map<Object, String> select1Map;
    @Getter         private Map<Object, String> select2Map;

    @Getter @Setter private String select1;
    @Getter @Setter private String select2;

    public String display() {
        select1Map= service.getDataForDropDown(getUser().getId());
        if (select1!=null) {
            select2Map = service.getDataForDropDown2(select1);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }    
}
```

Note: `@Getter` and `@Setter` are [Lombok annotations](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html); it's great and I'll never go back, but here they just means *"put a getter and a setter"*.

Comment: It's rolling..., Lombok rulez.

Comment: @RomanC Yeah, every time you change a name, or a type, there's no need to erase and regenerate getters and setters. And with `@Data` on the class you have all of them at once (sometimes it's useful)...

Comment: is it working like Eclipse or like Struts by naming its methods?

Comment: I don't get what you mean here :|

Comment: I mean is it capitalize a method name it generates like Struts, or can have lowercase  letter after the get prefix, remember the issue that @Magno has asked?

Comment: Aaaah, I don't know, I never use variables with a single letter and then another capitalized word... should be tried, though!

Comment: You may ask the question for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to do something like this: http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/dynamic-drop-down-list-with-struts-2-and-ajax/

In this tutorial, the author uses jQuery to add an onChange() event to the first select box. When the user changes the value of the first box, jQuery will create an Ajax request back to a method in the action class to return the data associated with the current value selected.

Comment: There's also the struts2-jquery plugin that facilitates this operation for Struts2 users not familiar to jQuery (if any...): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994676/1654265